# cmake error in falkon compilation in yocto-krogoth

Tags: qt, cmake, cross-browser, qt5, yocto

I am trying to compile Falkon browser in yocto using qt5, aftre resloved so many errors getting error like below on cmake.

```
| CMake Warning at /home/siva/yocto/mira/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-7/usr/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake:7 (message):
|   SkippingbecauseOE_QMAKE_PATH_EXTERNAL_HOST_BINSisnotdefined
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   /home/siva/yocto/mira/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-7/usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMQueryQmake.cmake:1 (find_package)
|   /home/siva/yocto/mira/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-7/usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDEInstallDirs.cmake:459 (include)
|   CMakeLists.txt:15 (include)


| CMake Warning at /home/siva/yocto/mira/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-7/usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMQueryQmake.cmake:43 (message):
|   Failed call: qmake-qt5 -query "QT_INSTALL_PREFIX"
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   /home/siva/yocto/mira/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-7/usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDEInstallDirs.cmake:463 (query_qmake)
|   CMakeLists.txt:15 (include)

| CMake Error at /home/siva/yocto/mira/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-7/usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMQueryQmake.cmake:44 (message):
|   QMake call failed: No such file or directory
| Call Stack (most recent call first):
|   /home/siva/yocto/mira/build/tmp/sysroots/phyboard-mira-imx6-7/usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDEInstallDirs.cmake:463 (query_qmake)
|   CMakeLists.txt:15 (include)
```

BELOW IS MY RECIPE

```
DESCRIPTION = "falkon browser"
LICENSE = "GPL-3.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM=file://LICENSE.GPLv3;md5=8f0e2cd40e05189ec81232da84bd6e1a"
inherit qmake5 cmake systemd
require recipes-qt/qt5/qt5-git.inc

SRC_URI = "git://anongit.kde.org/falkon.git"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
DEPENDS = "qtbase qtdeclarative qtwebengine"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
PACKAGECONFIG ?= ""
PACKAGECONFIG[desktop] = "-DDESKTOP_BUILD,,"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += " \
    extra-cmake-modules \
    qtvirtualkeyboard \
    qtquickcontrols \
    qtwebengine \
    qtgraphicaleffects \
    qtmultimedia \
    ttf-dejavu \
"
```

Is there anything to add extra. I think installations variable problems?

Comment: `DEPENDS_${PN}` is not correct, it is `DEPENDS` or `RDEPENDS_${PN}`.

Comment: I have changed to "rdepends"  still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just open the Cmakefiles.txt in falkon source check the required  qt5 version.
I think this falkon browser requires atleast qt5.9. I guess you are using lowest version. So upgtrade your qt5 version to qt5.9.
or go for low version of falkon which requires qt5.6.

Comment: yes correct i am using qt5.6 now i got where is the error. but how can i upgrade qt5.6 to q5.9

Comment: I have upgraded the qt5.9 version still the  error is not solved same error coming